# In what economic systems, other than capitalism, do patents exist?

Tags: international, finance

Patents exist in capitalist systems. Do other economic systems have patents and, if so, what is their purpose in those systems?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Wikipedia article on the [Patent Cooperation Treaty (PCT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent_Cooperation_Treaty). It includes search authorities from countries including China and Russia.

Also, you can search [Google Patents](https://patents.google.com/) for patents from around the world which are often countries with different economic systems (China and Russia as major examples).

Finally, [Cooperative Patent Classification (CPC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_Patent_Classification) is a classification system that has been [agreed upon by both Europe and China](http://www.epo.org/news-issues/press/releases/archive/2013/20130604.html) to improve access to Chinese patent documentation.

And there are initiatives using machine translation to improve cooperation with [Russian and Eurasian](http://www.epo.org/news-issues/news/2013/20130926.html) regions.

Answer (score 0):

Patent system existed in Soviet Union but IP was owned by the state.